# Excel Macro Pt. 1 - Search Worksheet Column for USER generated INPUT and Move Row to new Worksheet

Tags: excel, row, vba

Hi I am in the process of sorting through a lot of data,  about 340,000 rows in total.  Ultimately just about every row will be massaged some way or another.   I am having trouble with step 1, sorting the data.

I will manually separate the data to different worksheets.  I will then Run a macro and the following will happen:    A prompt will ask the user what to search for, ie.  "TEXT" and then ask the user which column to search in,  ie.  "H".    The macro will then copy the entire row which meets the above into a new workbook and automatically save the workbook as a .csv file prompting the user for the name.   The new workbook could have several hundred matches, so it must append the row to the next.   Of course I am a newbie and I have used other peoples code and a bit of my own.

The code below is close.   I have the following issues:

I can not figure out how to manually enter the go back to sheetX to continue searching.   I would like this to be the current sheet or use the user prompt that is currently commented out.

I can get it to move to a new sheet but as stated above would like it to be a new workbook instead.

Thank You!

```
    Public strData2 As String
    Public strSearchSheet As String
    Public strRange2 As String





Sub NewSearch()

'User Prompt box to enter IO driver type
 strData2 = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter IO Driver type you wish to search.  (IE GE9).", _
       Title:="ENTER TYPE", Default:="Type here")

 'strSearchSheet = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Sheet name to search.  (IE AI).", _
      Title:="ENTER TYPE", Default:="Type here")
 'User Prompt box to enter Column to search
 strRange2 = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Column you wish to search.  (IE E).", _
       Title:="ENTER TYPE", Default:="Type here")

  Dim LSearchRow As Integer
  Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

  'On Error GoTo Err_Execute

  'Start search in row 1
  LSearchRow = 1

  'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
  LCopyToRow = 2

  While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

   'If value in column  = "TEXT", copy entire row to Sheet2
   If Range(strRange2 & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = strData2 Then

     'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
     Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
     Selection.Copy

     'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
     Sheets("Test").Select
     Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste

     'Move counter to next row
     LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

     'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
     Sheets("AO").Select

  End If

  LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

       Wend


      'Position on cell A3
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       Range("A3").Select

       MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

       Exit Sub

   Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."

    End Sub
```

Comment: What is your actual question, what code have you already written, and what troubleshooting steps have you performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.Select` is your culprit. If you don't select another sheet, you will not have to save your position. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179) for an excellent reason why `Select` is not a good idea.

this entire code block:

```
 'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
 Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
 Selection.Copy

 'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
 Sheets("Test").Select
 Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
```

can be put into a single line that doesn't lose your place

```
 'Copy from row LSearchrow to LCopyToRow in Test sheet
 Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Copy _
    Sheeets("Test").Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow))
```

(broken into 2 lines for readability) and this won't change workseets, so your place is not lost when searching

If you want to create a new workbook, then `Workbooks.Add` will add a new workbook. If you assign the new workbook to a variable, then you can manipulate it using the same commands you can use on the current workbook.

e.g.

```
Dim NewWS As Workbook
Set NewWS = Workbooks.Add
NewWS.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 3
NewWS.SaveAs "myFilename.csv", xlCSV
NewWS.Close
```